# Problem with "save and continue editing"

Tags: craft3, admin, redirect

i have some weird behaviour in my craft installation. It came after some update not sure when.

The problem is when i use "save and continue editing" button (or shortcode) then i'm redirected to wrong url. Post / Asset is saved but i'm redirected to not existed page.

example: init url: http://mydomain.test/admin/assets/myCompanyMedia/204885-bird-gf3c26a528_1920?site=default

url after save: http://mydomain.test/admin/%EF%BB%BFhttp://mydomain.test/admin/assets/myCompanyMedia/204885-bird-gf3c26a528_1920?site=default

Is anybody know where i can start looking?

Comment: Are you using Craft Lite or Craft Pro? Check out the section settings for the section you're getting this error with, in particular the URL settings. For Craft Pro, check the preview URL settings as well. Please post a screenshot of all of those. Also, what are your siteUrl / baseUrl settings?

Comment: @MoritzLost thank you for respons. I'm using Craft Pro v.3.6.5

`.evv
CRAFTENV_BASE_URL="http://mydomain.test/"
ASSETS_BASE_URL="http://mydomain.test"`

assets settings base url for this volume:
`http://mydomain.test/default/mycompanymedia`

in volumes.php i have
`'myCompanyMedia' => [
   'url' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL') . 'default/mycompanymedia/',
   'path' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH') . 'default/mycompanymedia'
  ],`